# Java Deadlock during a synchronized on a local resource?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, deadlock

I'm seeing a problem with multiple Threads deadlocking on the same line of code.
I cannot reproduce the problem locally or in any test, but yet Thread Dumps from Production have show the problem quite clearly.

I can't see why the Threads would become blocked on the synchronized line below, since there is no other synchronization on the Object in the call stack or in any other Thread. Does anyone have any idea what is going on, or how I can even reproduce this issue (Currently trying with 15 Threads all hitting trim() in a loops, while processing 2000 tasks through my Queue - But unable to reproduce)

In the Thread dump below, I think the multiple Threads with the 'locked' status may be a manifestation of Java Bug: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8047816 where JStack reports Threads in wrong state. 
(I'm using JDK Version: 1.7.0_51)

Cheers!

Here is a view of the Threads in the Thread dump.....

```
"xxx>Job Read-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aca001a6800 nid=0x6a3b waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000052ec4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.remove(CustomQueue.java:101)
    - locked <0x00002aae6465a650> (a java.util.ArrayDeque)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trim(CustomQueue.java:318)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.itemProcessed(CustomQueue.java:302)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trackCompleted(CustomQueue.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00002aaf5f9c2680> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"xxx>Job Read-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aca001a5000 nid=0x6a3a waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000052d83000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.remove(CustomQueue.java:101)
    -  locked <0x00002aae6465a650> (a java.util.ArrayDeque)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trim(CustomQueue.java:318)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.itemProcessed(CustomQueue.java:302)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trackCompleted(CustomQueue.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00002aaf5f9ed518> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"xxx>Job Read-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aca00183000 nid=0x6a39 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000052c42000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.remove(CustomQueue.java:101)
    - waiting to lock <0x00002aae6465a650> (a java.util.ArrayDeque)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trim(CustomQueue.java:318)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.itemProcessed(CustomQueue.java:302)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trackCompleted(CustomQueue.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00002aaf5f9ecde8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


"xxx>Job Read-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000006a83000 nid=0x6a36 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000005287f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.remove(CustomQueue.java:101)
    - waiting to lock <0x00002aae6465a650> (a java.util.ArrayDeque)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trim(CustomQueue.java:318)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.itemProcessed(CustomQueue.java:302)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trackCompleted(CustomQueue.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the Java code extracted, which shows where the error is...

```
public class Deadlock {
        final Deque<Object> delegate  = new ArrayDeque<>();
        final long maxSize = Long.MAX_VALUE;

        private final AtomicLong totalExec = new AtomicLong();
        private final Map<Object, AtomicLong> totals = new HashMap<>();
        private final Map<Object, Deque<Long>> execTimes = new HashMap<>();

        public void trim() {
            //Possible optimization is evicting in chunks, segmenting by arrival time
            while (this.totalExec.longValue() > this.maxSize) {
                final Object t = this.delegate.peek();
                final Deque<Long> execTime = this.execTimes.get(t);
                final Long exec = execTime.peek();
                if (exec != null && this.totalExec.longValue() - exec > this.maxSize) {
                    //If Job Started Inside of Window, remove and re-loop
                    remove();
                }
                else {
                    //Otherwise exit the loop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public Object remove() {
            Object removed;
            synchronized (this.delegate) { //4 Threads deadlocking on this line !
                removed = this.delegate.pollFirst();
            }
            if (removed != null) {
                itemRemoved(removed);
            }
            return removed;
        }

        public void itemRemoved(final Object t) {
            //Decrement Total & Queue
            final AtomicLong catTotal = this.totals.get(t);
            if (catTotal != null) {
                if (!this.execTimes.get(t).isEmpty()) {
                    final Long exec = this.execTimes.get(t).pollFirst();
                    if (exec != null) {
                        catTotal.addAndGet(-exec);
                        this.totalExec.addAndGet(-exec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not a deadlock when you are not already holding a lock while waiting to lock a second one. Which thread is currently holding the contested lock (0x000000005287f000)?

Comment: That's a lot of `Deque`s you have; why don't you "bundle" the `Object` and its exec times into a same class? That would simplify your code considerably (imho). Also, why don't you just use a thread safe `BlockingQueue` instead?

Comment: Just to note that `this.` everywhere is completely unnecessary.

Comment: It seems noteworthy that `Read-2` and `Read-3` are both shown as having *locked* the same monitor. Since I assume that the thread dump is not a stop-the-world event, this would prove that you are actually not observing any deadlocks, or even blocking---just high lock contention. Compatible with what *Boris the Spider* said.

Comment: Changing the HashMap's to ConcurrentHashMap's and ArrayDequeue's to LinkedBlockingDeque's as well as making the trim method synchronized seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the responses here, it became clear that the issue was none Thread Safe usage of multiple Collections.

To resolve the issue, I've made the trim method synchronized and replaced usage of HashMap with ConcurrentHashMap and ArrayDeque with LinkedBlockingDeque
(Concurrent Collections FTW!)

A further planned enhancement is to change the usage of 2 separate Maps into a single Map containing a Custom Object, that way keeping the operations (in itemRemoved) atomic.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation for `HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

(Emphasis theirs)

You are both reading and writing to/from the `Map`s in an unsynchronized manner.

I see no reason to assume that your code is thread safe.

I suggest that you have an infinite loop in `trim` caused by this lack of thread safety.

Entering a synchronized block is relatively slow, so it's likely that a thread dump will always show at least a few threads waiting to obtain the lock.

Comment: This is only true if there are modification.  There may be modifications but we can't tell based on the code.

Comment: @JohnVint the code allows for modification. If modification occurs, the code becomes unpredictable. This code is not thread safe - there is no point in analysing it further.

Comment: If the OP chooses to use a `HashMap` that will never change as the code is designed there is absolutely nothing wrong with it.  Needlessly `synchronizing` on a non-mutating HashMap is wrong.

Comment: it's true, if the map was built before any of the problematic tasks starting, the code should be deemed thread-safe.

Comment: Changing the HashMap's to ConcurrentHashMap's and ArrayDequeue's to LinkedBlockingDeque's as well as making the trim method synchronized seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: @Ro that's most likely overkill. If it's not performance critical, then that's fine. But as it's concurrent code, I imagine it's fairly critical. Using thread safe collections and `synchronized` is a waste - thread safe collections were designed exactly so that you don't have to. Consider thinking more carefully about design, and using atomic operations (such as `putIfAbsent` and `computeIfAbsent`) and avoiding `synchronized`.

Comment: Thanks Boris .... I've removed all synchronization blocks around the delegate Object, since making it a LinkedBlockingDeque

Answer (score 1):

Your first thread is holding the lock while waiting for `pollFirst`.

```
"xxx>Job Read-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aca001a6800 nid=0x6a3b waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000052ec4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.remove(CustomQueue.java:101)
    - locked <0x00002aae6465a650> (a java.util.ArrayDeque)
    at com.mycompany.collections.CustomQueue.trim(CustomQueue.java:318)
```

The other threads are waiting to obtain the lock.
You will need to provide the entire thread dump to determine which thread is holding the lock on `0x0000000052ec4000`, which is what is preventing your `pollFirst` call from returning.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deadlock, you need at least two be locking on at least two objects in the same thread at the same time which is something the code you posted doesn't appear to do.  The bug you point to may apply but as I read it, it's a cosmetic issue and that the threads are not 'locked', but waiting to acquire a lock on the object in question (the ArrayDeque).  You should see a "deadlock" message in your logs if you have a deadlock.  It will call out the two threads that are blocking each other.

I don't believe the thread dump says there are deadlocks.  It's simply telling you how many threads are waiting on the monitor at the moment you took the dump.  Since only one thread may have the monitor at a given moment, it shouldn't be very surprising.

What behavior are you seeing in your application that lead you to believe you have a deadlock?  There's a lot missing from your code particularly where the objects in the delegate Dequeue are coming from.  My guess is you don't have an outright deadlock but some other issue that may look like a deadlock.